# Where did the names in the Divide books come from?

Tags: the-divide, elizabeth-kay

Elizabeth Kay's [*Divide* books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Divide_trilogy) feature a range of characters, some named after plants (Betony, Snakeweed, Tansy), some brazzle-style with materials and body parts (Ironclaw, Thornbeak, Stonetalon), and some normal human names (Felix).

**What, if anything, do we know about the (out of universe) origin of these names?**

E.g. was betony a favourite plant of the author's? Was Felix named after someone she knew? Is there any information (e.g. from author interviews) about this?

Comment: Not an answer, but related and interesting: "*a few of the more eccentric characters in the Divide
books were inspired by real people. The person you know better than anyone else is, of course, yourself – so you use aspects of yourself quite a lot as well. The adventurous bit of me went into the elf Betony, the indecisive bit into the sinistrom Grimspite, and the rebellious bit into the gryphon Fuzzy.*" -- [Elizabeth Kay](http://authorselectric.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/ive-got-stuck-elizabeth-kay.html)